# Is it possible to implement the argument unpacking operators (aka splash operators) as a function?

Tags: python

Scenario:

```
kwargs = dict(a=1, b=2)
def test(a=None, b=None): return a, b

def unpack(kwargs):
    ...
    return whatever    

test(unpack(kwargs))  # instead of test(**kwargs)
>> 1, 2
```

The only solution my tired mind could crank up atm is to reverse the whole jumble
as in:

```
def unpack(f, kwargs):
    return f(**kwargs)

unpack(test, kwargs)
>> 1, 2
```

As for why:
There is no immediate need. But i was wondering out of curiosity if an `unpack` function was
feasible, in general.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, it is not possible. Argument unpacking is part of the *call syntax*, not the expression that produces an argument.

The Python parser and compiler turns the syntax into specialised bytecode. A function would not be able to replicate the work done to unpack objects into arguments without those.

Instead, produce both a positional arguments list and a keyword arguments dictionary, and *always* apply those, even if empty:

```
def update_kwargs(kwargs):
    # update the dictionary

args, kwargs = [], {}
update_kwargs(kwargs)
test(*args, **kwargs)
```

An empty list for `*args` or empty dictionary for `**kwargs` will simply result in no arguments being applied at all.

Comment: I was aware of it being part of the syntax. I am just researching if there is some creative way, to bypass these restrictions. Nevertheless you gave a very precise answer and i will likely accept it later, if no other creative solution is proposed. Your help is very appreciated.

Comment: This is one area, where i do not like the splash-operator: It obfuscates the call-signature and that's why i try to use them as seldom as possible.

Comment: @DonQuestion: I like it a lot better than the old [`apply()` function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#apply).

Comment: But at least it did not mess with the call signature at definition time. ;-) Now i have to document every parameter manually! ;-)